# Make alt tag display quicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

Is there anyway to get the alt tag to display quicker?

Also, I notice it doesn't show in all browsers. I know I should craft a javascript tooltip but I am looking for something really lite with minimal code.

Comment: `alt` is an _attribute_, not a tag.  For a tooltip, you should use the `title` attribute.

Comment: There's nothing in the spec for `alt` attributes to be displayed as tooltips—it just so happens that IE displays them that way.  The `title` attribute is probably what you want.

Comment: To add to this: Think **alt** means alternative. In other words, if the **img** doesn't load or my users can't see it (sight-impaired users), what Alternative text do I want to display? If it's a graphic with words like "Buy Now!" alt='Buy now' would be a good choice. If it's a graphical element: alt='' is great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **alt** attribute is meant to show up if the img is NOT shown. You probably want to use the **title** attribute if you're specifying tooltips.

**How fast it displays is browser ( or OS ) dependent. You can't control it with html or CSS.**

A good alternative would be to program a javascript alternative with jQuery.

See this page for some ideas:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/

Answer (score 4):

The speed at which an alt tag displays is a function of the browser software and possibly OS-based settings. You're only going to get a faster response with a custom script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Tooltips](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/) to show the Title Attribute faster and nicer :) Not Alt...

Here is a good [Tutorial](http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/) with more than 25 examples...