# is there a way to make the default browser tooltip appear faster?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make alt tag display quicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493968/make-alt-tag-display-quicker)

I was wondering if there was a simple way to make the default browser tooltip appear faster (immediately).